# Find mode for each group in pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with the following 3 columns: property, value, count

Pairs of (property, value) are unique.

I need to add a new column to this dataframe, that will check if the value in count is the most frequent within its property column value. So, for example:

We have a dataframe

```
property,value,count
p1,v1,20
p1,v2,50
p1,v3,50
p2,v4,10
p2,v5,20
```

And as a result we need to get:

```
property,value,count,is_mode
p1,v1,20,False
p1,v2,50,True
p1,v3,50,True
p2,v4,10,True
p2,v5,20,False
```

- in case when there are multiple modes I need to use the minimum one for calculating the is_mode value. So here, for p2 there are modes - 10, 20, but since I need the minimum one, for 10 is_mode will be True and for 20 it will be False

I've found numerous solutions from stackoverflow already, but these didn't lead me to any good result.
For some reason

I tried to split the task into first getting the mode for each property and then somehow compare the values to the minimum mode for this group:

```
new_df = df.groupby(["property"])["count"].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

same if I try to attach it to the current dataframe:

```
properties["mode"] = properties.groupby(["property"])["count"].transform(pd.Series.mode)
```

these doesn't crush however they produce weird results with lots of Nans. For example, I have:

```
property,value,count
p1,v1,200
p1,v2,60
p1,v3,60
```

and expect to get:

```
property,value,count,mode
p1,v1,200,60
p1,v2,60,60
p1,v3,60,60
```

but in my case I get:

```
property,value,count,mode
p1,v1,200,NaN
p1,v2,60,NaN
p1,v3,60,NaN
```

Comment: Your input is unclear, it looks like you already have the counts. In this case you should use `max` not `mode`. Or did you mean the mode of the counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the smallest mode of the counts per group, use a custom function and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

For each group, get the [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) (one or more values), then the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html), flag values that are equal to it:

```
df['is_mode'] = (df.groupby('property')['count']
                   .transform(lambda s: s.eq(s.mode().min()))
                )
```

Output:

```
  property value  count  is_mode
0       p1    v1     20    False
1       p1    v2     50     True
2       p1    v3     50     True
3       p2    v4     10     True
4       p2    v5     20    False
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for! Thank you so much for such a beautiful solution!